# Execute the navigate URL when the node is selected programmatically

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik

I am using Telerik RadTreeView and I am adding Nodes programatically with the following code

```
     subnode.NavigateUrl = "javascript:selectedNode('" + subnode.Text + "','" + "content" + "','" + myDataReader2["moduleId"] + "')";

RadTreeView1.Nodes.Add(subnode);
```

Thus when i am clicking the node then the javascript function selectedNode is executed. But when I am changing the selected node programmatically by using a button for ex:

```
 node.Focus();
 node.Selected = true;
```

The javascript is not executed. Is there any way to execute its navigateurl property ?.

Comment: Try to do something like this: radTreeView1.SelectedNode = theNode;

Comment: The node is selected successfully. But its navigateURL is not executed.

Comment: If you then create a method that is linked to the AfterSelect event of a treeview, you can trigger the redirect manually. Hope this helps.

Comment: hm but there is no event that fires when a selected node is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the tree's OnClientNodeClicked event.
You can set the value of the node to "moduleId" in your code behind.

```
subnode.Value = myDataReader2["moduleId"];
RadTreeView1.Nodes.Add(subnode);
```

Then in javascript, on your clientnodeclicked event, do something like this

```
function NodeClicked(sender, args) {
    var node = args.get_node();
    selectedNode(node.get_text(), "content", node.get_value());
}
```